# c preprocessor for templating - suppress extra artefacts

Tags: c, dockerfile, preprocessor

Command :

```
% cat <<EOF | cpp -DVERBOSE=3
#if VERBOSE >= 2
  printf("trace message");
#endif
EOF
```

Output :

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 362 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>" 2

  printf("trace message");
```

Anyone know how to suppress those lines such as `# 1 "<stding>" 2`, I need to include some instructions like `# dockerfile syntax=experiemental` in the input Dockerfile.

Comment: `I need to include some instructions like # dockerfile syntax=experiemental in the input Dockerfile.` How is this related to the C preprocessor? Are you asking an XY problem?

Comment: Also, I need to include some instructions like # dockerfile syntax=experiemental in the input Dockerfile. My bad. I don't think it's possible to have them ignored. I'll leave the question as written so there's context around your feedback KamilCuk. Ability to express myself clearly was degraded by about 4 hours going around in circles - this is the docker way ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to suppress those lines such as # 1 "" 2

From [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -P

> Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which might be confused by the linemarkers.

```
cpp -P ...
```